# PinchGesture Zoom like Instagram mobile feed screen in Xamarin Form

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, zooming, pinch

I am trying to implement similar zoom functionality like Instagram mobile app feed screen in xamarin cross-platform app.
Actually I want to add pinch gesture on `ImageView` inside `ListView` cell, if user pinch on image, it should zoom-in over `ListView`. Once user release pinch it should automatically resize to original size and fit to cell.
Help me and provide solution.

Following sample code working but its zooming inside the cell, its not like Instagram zooming overlap/overlay effect.

XAML code

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" ItemSelected="PlayerList_OnItemSelected"  HasUnevenRows="false" RowHeight="300" BackgroundColor="#F6F3F6" 
RelativeLayout.XConstraint=
"{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
Property=Width, Factor=0}" 

RelativeLayout.YConstraint=
"{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
Property=Height, Factor=.09}"

RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint=
"{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
Property=Height, Factor=.91}"

RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint=
"{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
Property=Width, Factor=1}">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
<ViewCell >
<Frame Margin="5" Padding="5"  OutlineColor="White" HasShadow="true">

<RelativeLayout >
<Label Font="Bold,20" Text="{Binding name}" TextColor="Black"
        RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression 
        Type=RelativeToParent,
        Property=Height,
        Factor=.0}"
        RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression 
        Type=RelativeToParent, 
        Property=Width, 
        Factor=.02}"
        RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression 
        Type=RelativeToParent, 
        Property=Width,
        Factor=.9}"/>

    <local:PinchToZoomContainer RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
        Type=RelativeToParent,
        Property=Width, 
        Factor=1}"
        RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
        Type=RelativeToParent,
        Property=Width, 
        Factor=0}" 

        RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression 
        Type=RelativeToParent, 
        Factor=.15, 
        Property=Height}">

        <local:PinchToZoomContainer.Content>
                <Image x:Name="imgBg" HeightRequest="180" Aspect="AspectFill" BackgroundColor="#F0F3F4"  Margin="1,1,1,-1" Source="{Binding thumbnail, Converter={StaticResource GetFeedImage}}" />
            </local:PinchToZoomContainer.Content>
        </local:PinchToZoomContainer>


    <Label FontSize="10" TextColor="#96AAC0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" HeightRequest="40" Text="{Binding posted_at}" 
        RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression 
        Type=RelativeToParent,
        Property=Height,
        Factor=.02}"
        RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression 
        Type=RelativeToParent, 
        Property=Width, 
        Factor=.81}"
        RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression 
        Type=RelativeToParent, 
        Property=Width,
        Factor=.2}"/>

    <Label FontSize="12" TextColor="#5B636E" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"  Text="{Binding description}" 
        RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression 
        Type=RelativeToParent,
        Property=Height,
        Factor=.87}"
        RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression 
        Type=RelativeToParent, 
        Property=Width, 
        Factor=.01}"
        RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression 
        Type=RelativeToParent, 
        Property=Width,
        Factor=.98}"

        RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression 
        Type=RelativeToParent, 
        Property=Height,
        Factor=0,
        Constant=30}"/>
</RelativeLayout>
    </Frame>
</ViewCell>
</DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>

</ListView>
```

Zoom container class

```
public class PinchToZoomContainer : ContentView
{
double currentScale = 1;
double startScale = 1;
double xOffset = 0;
double yOffset = 0;

public PinchToZoomContainer ()
{
    var pinchGesture = new PinchGestureRecognizer ();
    pinchGesture.PinchUpdated += OnPinchUpdated;
    GestureRecognizers.Add (pinchGesture);

}

void OnPinchUpdated (object sender, PinchGestureUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Status == GestureStatus.Started) {
        // Store the current scale factor applied to the wrapped user interface element,
        // and zero the components for the center point of the translate transform.
        startScale = Content.Scale;
        Content.AnchorX = 0;
        Content.AnchorY = 0;
    }
    if (e.Status == GestureStatus.Running) {
        // Calculate the scale factor to be applied.
        currentScale += (e.Scale - 1) * startScale;
        currentScale = Math.Max (1, currentScale);

        // The ScaleOrigin is in relative coordinates to the wrapped user interface element,
        // so get the X pixel coordinate.
        double renderedX = Content.X + xOffset;
        double deltaX = renderedX / Width;
        double deltaWidth = Width / (Content.Width * startScale);
        double originX = (e.ScaleOrigin.X - deltaX) * deltaWidth;

        // The ScaleOrigin is in relative coordinates to the wrapped user interface element,
        // so get the Y pixel coordinate.
        double renderedY = Content.Y + yOffset;
        double deltaY = renderedY / Height;
        double deltaHeight = Height / (Content.Height * startScale);
        double originY = (e.ScaleOrigin.Y - deltaY) * deltaHeight;

        // Calculate the transformed element pixel coordinates.
        double targetX = xOffset - (originX * Content.Width) * (currentScale - startScale);
        double targetY = yOffset - (originY * Content.Height) * (currentScale - startScale);

        // Apply translation based on the change in origin.
        Content.TranslationX = targetX.Clamp (-Content.Width * (currentScale - 1), 0);
        Content.TranslationY = targetY.Clamp (-Content.Height * (currentScale - 1), 0);

        // Apply scale factor
        Content.Scale = currentScale;
    }
    if (e.Status == GestureStatus.Completed) {
        // Store the translation delta's of the wrapped user interface element.
        xOffset = Content.TranslationX;
        yOffset = Content.TranslationY;

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Until you provide some code what you have tried, no one can help. People need to know the context, how your list cell look like..etc

Comment: Following sample code working but its zooming inside the cell, its not like Instagram zooming overlap/overlay effect. please check sample code  i have added.alo its not smooth like Instagram app

Comment: here is the instagram feed page video, I want exactly same features.https://www.dropbox.com/s/8ctwqjo86qpsqku/Video%20Aug%2010%2C%204%2014%2036%20PM.mp4?dl=0

Comment: HI did you got any solution for this?